# Bash comparing value with zero

Tags: linux, bash

What is wrong with this piece of bash script:

```
OIFS=$IFS;
IFS=$IFS;
IFS=",";
tables=($1);

len="${#tables[@]}";

if [ $len -eq 0 ]; then
    tables=("a,b,c");
fi;

IFS=$OIFS

for ((i=0; i < $len; ++i));
do
    echo "table ${tables[$i]}";
done
```

Why `if [ $len -eq 0 ];` fails to evaluate ?  The idea is to set default list of tables if arguments to script are missing. Please advise me !

**Desired output**
a) with arguments:

```
./test.sh "x,y,z"
table x
table y
table z
```

b) without arguments:

```
 ./test.sh 
    table a
    table b
    table c
```

*I am really sorry if this script offended someone, I am genuinely here to get help and novice in bash scripting.Its really dis-heating to push someone hard when he is asking for help.I ll twice think before posting a question to "bash" community.Yes I will be wrong always bcz I am asking for help and was here with good-faith*

cheers

**Edit Whole working script, after your suggestions**

```
#!/bin/bash
#author: sakhunzai
#usages: usage: ./change_db_engine.sh -h [Show help and exit] -u [dbuser] -p[dbpwd] -d[dbname] -e [engine] [csv tables]

NL=$'\n'

function usage() {

echo "$NL   $1 $NL
    usage:  $0 -h [Show help and exit] -u [dbuser] -p[dbpwd] -d[dbname] -e [engine] [csv tables]
    Author:sakhunzai$NL";
exit;
}

while getopts  ":hu:p:d:e:" opt; do
   case $opt in
        'h') usage " *** Usage Help **** ";;
        'u') usr=$OPTARG;;
        'p') pwd=$OPTARG;;
        'd') db=$OPTARG;;
        'e') engine=$OPTARG;;
         \?)
            usage "Invalid arguments '-$OPTARG'" ;;
   esac
done

if [ -z $usr ] ; then
   usage "-u [dbuser] missing";
fi;

if [ -z $pwd ] ; then
   usage "-p [dbpwd] missing";
fi;

if [ -z $db ] ; then
   usage "-d [dbname] missing";
fi;

if [ -z $engine ] ; then
   usage "-e [engine] missing";
fi;


shift $((OPTIND - 1));
# list of tables to be changes separated by comma
IFS=, read -a tables <<< "$1"

if [ "${#tables[@]}" -eq 0 ]; then
    tables=($(mysql -u$usr -p$pwd $db  -e"show tables" | tr '\n', ' '));
    unset tables[0]
    tables=( "${tables[@]}" )
fi;

for ((i=0; i < "${#tables[@]}"; ++i));
do
    echo "ALTER TABLE ${tables[$i]} ENGINE = InnoDB; ";
done
```

definitely there might be some ugly code.

Comment: It works fine to me with bash. What error are you getting?

Comment: I am on Mac OSx , the if section fails when no arguments passed

Comment: There is no need for semicolon at EOL in shell scripts.

Comment: please check the updates, I never get the idea of down voting in no time

Comment: The statement `IFS=$OIFS` is not meaningful unless you do a `OIFS=$IFS` first. Now you're doing `IFS=$IFS` which does nothing. And to iterate over an array in bash, use `for x in "${arr[@]}" ...` rather than dealing with indices.

Comment: fixed the OIFS=$IFS thing , thanks.I missed that out during cut-past

Comment: @sakhunzai don't let a single downvoter get you down. A single downvote is from a single person who may or may not be sane. Please don't judge the whole community by it.

Comment: @kojiro, its good to see ppl like you around , thanks for your help

Comment: @sakhunzai You may want to acquaint yourself with codereview.stackexchange.com if you want full code review on working scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked "what is wrong?" Here goes:

```
OIFS=$IFS; # Lots of unnecessary semicolons
IFS=$IFS; # This does nothing.
IFS=",";
tables=($1); # Why jump through hoops to redo wordsplitting? Something smells off with this, like you're making it too complicated.

len="${#tables[@]}";

if [ $len -eq 0 ]; then
```

I'd probably do `if (( !$len )); then` here, but there's nothing really wrong with this.

```
    tables=("a,b,c");
```

This doesn't do what you want, even if you remove the quotes. Here's what the manual has to say about `IFS`:

> The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after expansion  and  to  split lines  into  words  with the read builtin command.  The default value is `<space><tab><new-line>`.

the key phrase there is "after expansion". Even if you remove the quotes, the value will be an array with a single element "a,b,c". You could force expansion with `foo='a,b,c'; tables=($foo)`, but that's awfully contrived. What you really want here is `tables=(a b c)`.

```
fi;

IFS=$OIFS

for ((i=0; i < $len; ++i));
```

I would write this `for i in "${!tables[@]}"; do`. This will loop over whatever the existing array keys are, instead of manually constructing a list of keys you hope exist. Consider that bash arrays are sparse. Also consider you're skipping the zeroth element.

```
do
    echo "table ${tables[$i]}";
done
```

I think this whole loop could be rewritten `printf table %s\n' "${tables[@]}"`, but maybe you need it for another purpose.

I don't see anything that would prevent the length-of-tables test from working as intended. Indeed, if you give the script an argument of *anything*, the value will be nonzero. If you give the script no arguments, the value will be 0, and the `if` block will happen.

*However, since you're skipping the zeroth argument in your loop, if the tables array has only one value, it will never get printed.*

I don't have enough context to critique the comma-delimiting, but it does seem overcomplicated. Your comment in [l0b0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22382475/418413) makes me think you should just have the script take standard input. (You could also convert the `mysql` output to arguments using `mapfile`, `xargs` or `paste` possibly more effectively than using `tr`, but I would think `read` would be the best choice.)

Comment: I got the idea from http://timmurphy.org/2012/03/09/convert-a-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-bash/. I am still not getting why `table=(a,b,c)` is not affected by IFS , which is set to `,`

Comment: I am currently on Mac OSx , but later It will be used on any linux distro.

Comment: please see full script

Answer (score 2):

`tables=("a,b,c")` creates an array with a single element `a,b,c`, **not** a list with three table names. What you want is `tables=("a" "b" "c")`.

The entire script can be reduced to:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    set -- "a" "b" "c"
fi

for table
do
    echo "table $table"
done
```

Of course, using this you'd have to use `script.sh foo bar baz` instead of `script.sh foo,bar,baz`.

Comment: why not its working even $IFS being set to ",". Imagine doing this from database e.g `tables=("$(mysql -u$usr -p$pwd $db  -e"show tables" |tr '\n', ',')");`. If user params are missing I want to fetcht the values from database

Comment: @sakhunzai that kind of context would be greatly helpful in the question itself. Is there a particular reason you don't want the script to read the tables directly from stdin?

Answer (score 1):

You have a logic issue: you set the default table array when `$len -eq 0`, then later on when you output the array, your loop is `i=0; i < $len; ++i` - this means that you will never see the default table. You should change the default to:

```
if [ $len -eq 0 ]; then
    tables=(a b c);
    len=3;
fi;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `IFS` globally when you can help it. Use this instead:

```
IFS=, read -a tables <<< "$1"

len="${#tables[@]}"

if [ $len -eq 0 ]; then
    tables=(a b c);
fi

for t in "${tables[@]}"
do
    echo "table $t"
done
```